# JSON.parse produces a syntax error with php's json_encode method

Tags: php, javascript

I have a variable `$data['tree']`, that gets a row array from the database using a method, `get_tree($id)`, from the model.

In my view's js I using

```
var dbTree = JSON.parse(<?php echo $tree; ?>);
```

When I load the page I get `UncaughtSyntax Error: Unexpected token o` in chrome and in firefox I get `Syntax Error: Unexpected character`.

So When I inspected the script element with chrome the js looked like

```
var dbTree = JSON.parse({"id":"2","name":"sean","userId":"51fbd3f3a8f2ba1b5b000002","accountId":"51fbd3fca8f2ba1b5b000003","createdAt":"2013-08-02 16:09:34","numRuns":null,"contactExport":"","updatedAt":"2013-08-02 20:15:14","deployed":"1","template":"0","conversation_type":"Conversation"});
```

I don't see anything wrong with that can some help me out.

Comment: Seems like even `null` must be wrapped in quotes

Comment: You're trying to parse a JavaScript object, not JSON. Just get rid of the `JSON.parse()` call. The error is because your object is turned into the string `"[object Object]"`, which is seen as an array structure, but with the invalid character `o` as the first member.

Comment: You are right that JSON has to be parsed. But if you inject JSON in JavaScript *source code*, then the JSON will be interpreted as object literal, which doesn't have to and cannot be parsed. However please don't make the mistake to call object literals "JSON objects".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON.parse should be used with strings, not objects.

Or you even don't need to do anything. It is already an object.

Just like...

```
var dbTree = <?php echo $tree; ?>;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var dbTree = {"id":"2","name":"sean","userId":"51fbd3f3a8f2ba1b5b000002","accountId":"51fbd3fca8f2ba1b5b000003","createdAt":"2013-08-02 16:09:34","numRuns":null,"contactExport":"","updatedAt":"2013-08-02 20:15:14","deployed":"1","template":"0","conversation_type":"Conversation"};
// Test it works
console.log(dbTree);
```

Just get rid of parse function.

Comment: when I do that I get an unexpected token ; and when I remove the ; I get an unexpected identifier